# Does the zoom affect the amount of pokémon encountered?

Tags: pokemon-go

Lately it seems as if I get more Pokémon encounters when I zoom in more.

Is this just a stroke of odd luck, or does the zoom level affect the detection rate somehow?

Comment: Beware of apophenia in this game =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it shouldn't as the area loaded around you is always the same regardless of where you're looking and how zoomed you are.

Comment: Games like this have there spawn controlled server side, which makes it independent of the zoom of the player.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have an accepted answer but I'd like to give my thoughts. Most of the time I go out with my wife to catch pokémon and she uses the zoom between all in and all out and I always use all out, and if we are at the same GPS spot, we always see the same pokémon.